# Web Scraping a wikipedia page

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

In some wikipedia pages, after the title of the article (appearing in bold), there is some text inside of parentheses used to explain the pronunciation and phonetics of the words in the title. For example, on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diglossia), after the bold title **diglossia** in the `<p>`, there is an open parenthesis. In order to find the corresponding close parenthesis, you would have to iterate through the text nodes one by one to find it, which is simple. What I'm trying to do is find the very next href link and store it.

The issue here is that (AFAIK), there isn't a way to uniquely identify the text node with the close parenthesis and then get the following href. **Is there any straight forward (not convoluted) way to get the first link outside of the initial parentheses?**

#### EDIT

In the case of the link provided here, the href to be stored should be: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialects since that is the first link outside of the parenthesis

Comment: Are you using any lib like beautifulsoup to extract tags or just regex?

Comment: @GurupadHegde I'm just using python requests and lxml. Is there a way to do this with just those?

Comment: Check beautifulsoup once. You may get better parsing options.

Comment: @GurupadHegde Do you know how to do this in beautiful soup? If so, could you post an answer?

Comment: which href do you want exactly from your example url?

Comment: Are you trying to extract `"/wiki/Koine_Greek"`?

Comment: @GurupadHegde In this case, it should be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialects since that is the first link outside of the parenthesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import requests
rs = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diglossia', verify=False)
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(rs.text)
print parsed_html.body.findAll('p')[0].findAll('a')[0]
```

This gives:

```
<a href="/wiki/Linguistics" title="Linguistics">linguistics</a>
```

if you want to extract href then you can use this:

```
parsed_html.body.findAll('p')[0].findAll('a')[0].attrs[0][1]
```

**UPDATE**
It seems you want href after parentheses not the before one.
I have written script for it. Try this:

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
rs = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diglossia', verify=False)
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(rs.text)

temp = parsed_html.body.findAll('p')[0]

start_count = 0
started = False
found = False

while temp.next and found is False:
    temp = temp.next
    if '(' in temp:
        start_count += 1
        if started is False:
            started = True
    if ')' in temp and started and start_count > 1:
        start_count -= 1
    elif ')' in temp and started and start_count == 1:
        found = True

print temp.findNext('a').attrs[0][1]
```

Comment: I need the first link after the initial set of parentheses

Comment: are you working on only those wiki pages which have these parentheses explaining the pronunciation and phonetics of the words in the title?

Comment: so sometimes, it might not be in first paragraph like here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistics ?

Comment: In that case, you would just grab the first link which would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science. So as long as there are know parentheses for explaining the pronunciation, you can just get the first link. The issue is that when you are scraping multiple wiki articles, some have the initial set of parentheses and some don't. I'm writing a scraper to solve this problem [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Getting_to_Philosophy). I'm now just trying to handle the edge case I outlined in the post

Comment: I have updated the answer. Try it. Not sure if it is better than what you have though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139609/discussion-between-loremipsum1771-and-rohanil).

Comment: Nevermind, I made an edit to your answer that fixed the problem